# Check to see if a user has "edit rights" to a Google Drive URL

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-api

I'm trying to figure out how to check a Google Drive URL to see if a specific Gmail account has 'edit rights' to it. Is this possible in Apps Script? If yes, any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm currently researching `File.getEditors()`, but not sure how to test this code:

```
// Log the email address of all users who have edit access to a file.
//https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user

var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1mgw9xYO7X99brzrIk4Uel8YzndQa8dpGGQCnrFn4suU');
var editors = file.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(editors[i].getEmail());
}
```

Comment: Please clarify (in your question) the specific issue you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

To test this code, you need to place the code inside a a function inside the Script Editor on Google Drive, then execute the function.

You can access the Script Editor in two ways, either from within a spreadsheet (under Tools->Script Editor), in which case your script will be bound to the Spreadsheet.   Binding to a spreadsheet can be useful if you want the script to work with data from sheet, for example you might want to store some configuration settings in the sheet, in which case keeping the sheet and the code together as one file is convenient.

You can also create a stand alone Script by connecting the Google Apps Script app to your Google Drive (+New -> More -> Connect more apps), then creating a stand alone Google Apps Script file directly on drive.

Regardless of how you create the script, the behaviour of this script and the script editor will be exactly the same.

Once you are in the script editor, paste that code into a function (by default you will be given an empty function named "myFunction()". Then run it using the "Run" menu.

Finally, under the "View" menu, go to "Logs" to see the results of Logger.log().